# Update the the Nulls value with the previous one based on the date

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

From the following Table1 I want for the column `Name` when the column is null to update it with the previous value. I need to do this in SQL Developer.

For example:

Date1 - ID1 - NameA

Date2 - ID1 - Null

Update null with NameA

Table1

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/653539 . Also, by the "previous value" you mean previous by date?

Comment: Okk sorry, yes i mean by date

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a LAG window function like below which ignores NULLS.

See documentation [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions)

```
select datetime, id,
case when name is null 
then lag(name) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by id order by datetime ASC)
else name 
end
from 
yourtable
```

Comment: This is not working in an update statement, also i tried this but the result are not correct.